# Free Software for animating SVG

Tags: inkscape, svg, software-recommendation, animate

I use Inkscape which is capable of SVG output. I am trying to animate characters like Santa and export them as GIF. I am trying to do simple animations like the movement of legs, hands, head etc. Most of this can be achieved using rotate, move and scale. I am currently using Enve but it is a bit hard for me. I tried SynfigConfig as well. I used to have Adobe Flash a few years back and it was really easy to use. I tried Blender and it groups SVG in a funny way.

It will be nice if there is a simple enough free program which can help me add these simple movements to the SVG and export them as GIF or Webp. Thanks.

Comment: Hi there, have you read https://inkscape.org/learn/animation/ ?

Comment: Hi, thanks @AAGD , I tried most of them and found Enve very helpful. But something simpler would be nice. I love how Blender works. Sadly they group SVG in a strange way that it is hard to separate them. Otherwise, Blender has almost everything I am looking for.

Comment: Grouping while importing? How about importing layers that are already  separated instead?

Comment: @AAGD Not sure what you meant by that :blush I draw a Santa, it is mostly in a single layer.

Comment: Like if you want to animate his arms, import the arms separately... I can only guess what you want to achieve...

Comment: My images are normally complex. Face for eg, even eyes have 3 colours in it

Answer (score 2):

You got almost all options covered. So I can not add anything in that respect.

As I understand you are making a 2D animation. If you like how Blender works, probably you should adapt your workflow a bit.

I never use a vector file for animations if I really do not need to extrude a shape. So one option for complex images is to export as PNG each asset you need. Then import images as planes.

One advantage of this workflow is that you can make small adjustments and only export again the asset with the changes. You can even use PNG sequences as textures.

The animation will have a lot fewer objects in the Blend file.

Comment: Thanks. I hope that one day Blender would import SVG just like Enve.

Comment: Blender supports svg, you need to optimize it. The point is that using a texture instead of geometry is faster.